# Couldn't export data using content provider from client app

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I am practicing on content providers and currently writing 2 applications, Let say A and B. App A has a content provider, and I'm trying to use that provider inside App B. However, I couldn't achieve that.

App A:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<permission android:name="com.myapp.provider.PERMISSION" />
...
<application
...
<provider
            android:name=".provider.MyContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.myapp.provider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.myapp.provider.PERMISSION">
        </provider>
...
</application>
```

MyContentProvider.kt

```
class MyContentProvider : ContentProvider() {
    
    companion object {
        const val AUTHORITY = "com.myapp.provider"
        const val TABLE = "test"
        
        private const val URL = "content://$AUTHORITY/$TABLE" 
        val CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse(URL)
        
        const val ID = "_id"
        const val USERNAME = "username"
    }
    
    override fun onCreate(): Boolean = true

    override fun query(
        uri: Uri,
        projection: Array<out String>?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<out String>?,
        sortOrder: String?
    ): Cursor? = MatrixCursor(arrayOf(ID, USERNAME), 1).apply {
        addRow(arrayOf(1, "test"))
    }

    override fun getType(uri: Uri): String? = "vnd.android.cursor.item/$AUTHORITY.$TABLE"

    override fun insert(uri: Uri, values: ContentValues?): Uri? = null

    override fun delete(uri: Uri, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<out String>?): Int = -1

    override fun update(
        uri: Uri,
        values: ContentValues?,
        selection: String?,
        selectionArgs: Array<out String>?
    ): Int = -1
}
```

App B:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<uses-permission android:name = "com.myapp.provider.PERMISSION"/>
...
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val TAG = MainActivity::class.java.simpleName
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        ...
        
        val url = "content://com.myapp.provider/test"
        val cursor = this.contentResolver.query(Uri.parse(url), arrayOf("_id", "username"), "1=1", null, null)

        Log.d(TAG, "Count: ${cursor?.count}")
        Log.d(TAG, "ColumnCount: ${cursor?.columnCount}")

        if(cursor?.moveToFirst() == true) {
            val username: String? = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("username"))
            cursor.close()

            if(username.isNullOrBlank()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "username not found")
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "username found: $username")
            }
        } else {
            cursor?.close()
            Log.d(TAG, "Cursor is null")
        }
    }
}
```

I also wrote a test for App A to use that provider and the test has been passed. I guess the problem is about exporting the provider, but I couldn't find a solution to that situation.

App A:

MyContentProviderTest.kt

```
class MyContentProviderTest: ProviderTestCase2<MyContentProvider>(
    MyContentProvider::class.java, MyContentProvider.AUTHORITY) {
    
    private val TAG = MyContentProviderTest::class.java.simpleName
    
    lateinit var resolver: MockContentResolver

    override fun setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        resolver = mockContentResolver
    }
    
    fun testCase() {
        val cursor = resolver.query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)
        
        Assert.assertEquals(cursor?.count, 1)
        Assert.assertEquals(cursor?.columnCount, 2)
        
        cursor?.moveToFirst()
        
       Assert.assertEquals(cursor?.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.USERNAME)), "test")
        
    }
}
```